# SPLoaderError loadComponentError

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, react, typescript

I clone the [mentioned SharePoint App](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-securitygrid). Did a npm install. When I run gulp serve, it shows the following error. Please do the needful.

> [SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]: ***Failed to load component
>   "41e37f03-2ea8-4f19-b77a-f2121a1e7c45" (SpSecurityWebPart). Original
>   error: ***Failed to load entry point from component
>   "41e37f03-2ea8-4f19-b77a-f2121a1e7c45" (SpSecurityWebPart). Original
>   error: Error loading
>   https://component-id.invalid/41e37f03-2ea8-4f19-b77a-f2121a1e7c45_0.0.1
>   Cannot find module "./spSecurity.css"
>
> ***INNERERROR: ***Failed to load entry point from component "41e37f03-2ea8-4f19-b77a-f2121a1e7c45" (SpSecurityWebPart). Original
>   error: Error loading
>   https://component-id.invalid/41e37f03-2ea8-4f19-b77a-f2121a1e7c45_0.0.1
>   Cannot find module "./spSecurity.css" ***CALLSTACK:
>   t@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2019-02-01.006/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_ab51ffb0e2576c31246f5ed33d950474.js:272:16049
>   t@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2019-02-01.006/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_ab51ffb0e2576c31246f5ed33d950474.js:1143:21050
>   WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT

Comment: When trying to run any gulp task in Node 10.15.0, I get the following error: `const types = internalBinding('types'); `For this issue, did a `npm install natives@1.1.6.` The ReferenceError: internalBinding error is resolved. Then again I did the above mentioned steps. But having the same issue.

Comment: You need to install the Node v8.x version.

Answer (score 0):

SPFx currently doesn't support the latest Node 10.15.0 version. It doesnt support 9.x or 10.x version

You need to install the Node v8.x version.

Also, once you do that, you need to delete the `node_modules` folder and re-run `npm i` again and then test the project.

Reference - [Set up your SharePoint Framework development environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)

Install - [NodeJS LTS version 8.](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/)

Comment: same issue comes again.